Are KKT necessary optimality conditions in general non-convex problems? (with non-zero duality gap)
I have seen similar questions here, but have not been able to clarify mine.
KKT are necessary conditions for optimality if strong duality holds (Boyd and Vandenberghe, section 5.5.3). However, strong duality does not hold in general for non-convex problems (otherwise it would be easy to solve them, simply by solving the always convex dual problem). My question is: If strong duality doesn't hold, are KKT still necessary conditions for optimality?
If the answer is that KKT only make sense if strong duality holds, which are the optimality conditions when strong duality does not hold? Could you point me towards some text on the topic? I just want to understand it on a conceptual level, I don't need detailed math proofs.

For a non-convex but smooth constrained optimization problem, the KKT conditions are guaranteed to be satisfied if a mild “constraint qualification” condition is satisfied. Nocedal and Wright has a very good chapter about this.

How about a non-smooth, non-convex problem, such as an MILP? I understand that the stationarity condition can't be applied, as neither gradient nor subgradients can be computed, then do we have conditions for optimality in those problems? Related to this, if we can actually translate the integrality condition into some explicit non-convex constraint such as $x^2 = x$, then do the KKT work as necessary conditions? I guess we can't use this approach for a general MILP, but I don't see it clearly...
